# Any way to pass Math.random() to jQuery .css()?

Tags: jquery, colors, rgb

I am trying to make a random color generate each time I pass the mouse over a square div, but this code doesn't work. Is there a succinct way to do this?

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'rgb((Math.random()*255), (Math.random()*255),(Math.random()*255))')
```

Here is the whole block:

```
$('.square').mouseenter(function () {
    if (fade === true) {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#6f418c');
    } else if (colors === true) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb((Math.random()*255), (Math.random()*255),(Math.random()*255))');
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#42145F');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to put the JavaScript code for the random numbers into the style. That won't work. Instead you should concatinate the randoms into the string.

```
var fade = false;
var colors = true;

$('.square').mouseenter(function () {
    if (fade === true) {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#6f418c');
    } else if (colors === true) {
      $(this).css('background-color','rgb(' + parseInt(Math.random()*255) + ',' + parseInt(Math.random()*255) + ',' + parseInt(Math.random()*255) + ')')
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#42145F');
    }
  });
```

I have put the code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/smm9rbwa/

Answer (score 0):

A css rule cannot be javascript, and you give 'background-color' a string value. The css engine doesn't know what to do with that.
You could try this instead.

```
$(this).css('background-color','rgb(' +parseInt(Math.random()*255) +',' +parseInt(Math.random()*255) +',' +parseInt(Math.random()*255) +')')
```

Note: the parseInt() makes sure there's no decimals.